# Error trying to build Android application on Android Studio: Exception: already added

Tags: android, build, android-studio

When I try to build my Android project in Android Studio, I'm getting the following error -

```
Information:Compilation completed with 31 errors and 0 warnings in 4 sec
Information:31 errors
Information:0 warnings
Error:Android Dex: [main] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$menu;
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Dex: [main] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$id;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$dimen;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/BuildConfig;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$attr;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$layout;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$drawable;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$style;
Error:Android Dex: [main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lin/easyapps/android/myapplication/R$string;
Error:Android Dex: [main] 10 errors; aborting
```

Following is my build.gradle file from /app directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.easyapps.android.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Please help as I'm very new to Android Studio and have no idea as to what it means.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to have a look at the dependencies in your build.gradle files for each module. It probably doesn't like the fact for two modules you're depending on one module each time.

Comment: It seems that I have two build.gradle files, one in project root and another in app directory. First one doesn't hold much information, I pasted the second one in the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Do you only have one module in your project?

Comment: I think there are 3 modules, one says main, one r, and one build config.

Comment: You're looking for directories on the same level as your "app" folder.